# Printing both function and characters in python

Tags: python, function

How can I print both result of a function and characters?

```
x = input("Write your number: ")    
def fct1(n):
    if n == 10:
        print 'ten'         
def apple(n):
    return fct1(n) + 'apples'       
apple(x)
```

In my printing message I want to see `'ten apples'.` What is the problem?
This is not about only "ten" case. I explained shortly. Let's say I have in fct1(n) ten values. The point is I want to see 'three apples' or 'six apples' depending on the number I write

Comment: Try replace `print 'ten'` with `return 'ten'`.

Comment: For your last edit comment, have you tried `print apple(x)` instead of just `apple(x)` since actually you're using `return fct1(n) + 'apples'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the function if it does not return anything.

So you can either (on apple-function):

```
fct1(n)
print ' apples'
```

Or on fct1(n) you don't print the 'ten' string but instead return it:

```
return 'ten'
```

and then you can do `print fact(n) + apples` on the apple-function.

Using `return` is better if you need to do something else with the result after printing it.